# Is there any way to continue navigation stack of XCoordinator's routing with another one?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, cocoapods, coordinator-pattern

I use [XCoordinator](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/XCoordinator) in my app.

Let's imagine I have two coordinators: WelcomeCoordinator and HomeCoordinator. 
The first one is kind of NavigationCoordinator and the second one is probably too, but here is the deal: I want that HomeCoordinator initial route continues WelcomeCoordinator's navigation stack.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: There is no way to do that, as that will introduce some inconsistencies for what would happen if I call popToRoot on the second coordinator? should it go back to the verist controller on WelcomeCoordinator or Should it go back to first controller on HomeCoordinator?

Comment: I found a way to do that with a RedirectionCoordinator, thnx